# Cellular automata "convergence"?

Tags: recursion, sequence, automata, ca

My question is overall quite simple. Suppose one has a 1d CA and plot it's generations on a 2d grid of fixed width. If the length of the plot of its generations is not bounded, is there some sensible criterion too describe an end--a "convergence"--of this sequence? If there is, what necessary and sufficient conditions can be imposed on the CA and the seed which would allow one to know it converges without evaluating the sequence--what criterion makes this determinable or is this undecidable?

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton#Classification is certainly relevant here, but a profound, focussed answer would indeed be interesting.

Comment: [General 1D unbounded cellular automata are Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110). A bounded cellular automaton is a finite state machine, so it'll always enter a (possibly length-1) loop eventually.

Comment: Thanks. That helps me refine the terminology in the question a bit. I'm curious about how the number of states a cell can take on influences this too.

Comment: I'm not looking for a particular rule. The CA's does not necessarily have to be a particular width. I'm asking whether choosing from all 1D cellular automata of size n and choosing an arbitrary seed whether it's can be asserted the sequence will reach a homogeneous state.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, this is an undecidable problem. [The mortality problem is undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortality_(computability_theory))